# Control flow in restarts

Tags: common-lisp

I was just playing around with CL conditions and restarts after (re-)reading Practical Common Lisp Chapter 19 and I came across some behavior in a restart that I find a bit puzzling.

In the follwing snippet a restart is invoked which calls the function from which the condition was signalled with another argument.

```
(define-condition no-fun-allowed-condition nil nil)

(defun low (value)
  (format t "~&Before low.")

  (if (equal value "fun")
      (restart-case (signal 'no-fun-allowed-condition)
        (some-restart () (low "no-fun")))
      (format t "~&Running low with a non-fun value: '~A'" value))
  
  (format t "~&After low."))

(defun mid ()
  (format t "~&Before mid.")
  (low "fun")
  (format t "~&After mid."))

(defun high ()
  (handler-bind
      ((no-fun-allowed-condition
     #'(lambda (c)
         (declare (ignorable c))
         (invoke-restart 'some-restart))))
    (mid)))

(high)
```

This prints

```
Before mid.
Before low.
Before low.
Running low with a non-fun value: 'no-fun'
After low.
After low.
After mid.
```

Obviously "Before low" gets printed twice because of the restart, but what about "After low" running twice? The only explanation I can come up with is that since `handler-bind` doesn't unwind the call stack, the recursive call to `low` runs despite the restart. I was expecting the restart to intercept the control flow at this point though. Is this just a funny case because of the recursive call + side effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, after `handler-bind` execution continues as if nothing happened, so "after low" is reached (it is outside the `if`). It is interesting to note the order of it, so let's change it to `(format t "~&After low from ~a" value)` and run `(high)` again:

```
Before mid.
Before low.
Before low.
Running low with a non-fun value: 'no-fun'
After low from no-fun  <---- within the handler
After low from fun     <---- the first call continues
After mid.
```

With a non-local exit in the handler we wouldn't see the second "after low":

```lisp
(some-restart ()
          (low "no-fun")
          (return-from low))
```

If we use `handler-case`, this rewinds the stack and the second "after low" won't be reached, but in that case we need to re-write the example by defining the restart in the high-level caller. If it stayed in `low` it wouldn't exist when we wanted to use it. I went up with:

```lisp
(defun low (value)
  (format t "~&Before low with ~a." value)
  (if (equal value "fun")
      (signal 'no-fun-allowed-condition)
      (format t "~&Running low with a non-fun value: '~A'" value))
 
  (format t "~&After low from ~a" value))


(defun mid ()
  (format t "~&Before mid.")
  (low "fun")
  (format t "~&After mid."))


(defun high/case ()
  (handler-case
      (mid)
    (no-fun-allowed-condition ()
      (format t "~&!caught condition")
      (invoke-restart 'some-restart))))

;; actual caller:

(restart-case (high/case)
  (some-restart ()
    (low "no fun")))
```

gives:

```
Before mid.
Before low with fun.
!caught condition
Before low with no fun.
Running low with a non-fun value: 'no fun'
After low from no fun
```

Comment: cool, many thanks! omg the condition system is so cool! :)